# Should the React useMemo hook memoize repeat calls with same dependency values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an issue where a (fake) long running / expensive function inside a functional component doesn't appear to be memoized how I would think it would be.

From my understanding of memoization, calling a memoized function with the same param value would simply return the result of the previous call.

That is ONLY happening with useMemo (in my app at least) when values on the component change that are not in the dependencies list. I get that different values would need to rerun the expensive function again, but even if I call the function with a previously used value (value / primitive types, not reference types / objects), it re runs the expensive function again.

Either I've not got something quite right or my understanding of what useMemo does isn't quite right (is this where React.memo comes in?).

This can be seen in this rudimentary [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/blenko-use-memo).

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Comment: Can you post code to further understand how you are using the `useMemo` hook?

Comment: It's in Memoised.js in the stackblitz I linked to above .. although I can post on here if necessary.

Comment: I checked it out. The memoization is working as intended. You can see this by repeatidly clicking the "go" button. It does not recalculate because `value` is not changing. Since value is changing when you hit the + or - button, your input changes, thus the `useMemo` function runs the code.

If you replace the use memo line with this: `const total = expensiveOp(value)` and click "go" repeatidly, you will see it gets called every time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What are you thinking is you can say 50% correct.

`useMemo` does not execute the code again for same set of parameters, but

**It only remembers last value of parameters.**

In your example, when you are clicking + and - button, you are changing value of `value` from previous value.
On 2nd click if you are coming back to same value, it does not mean memoize will return value wothout executing the function.

Try to add a button and on click on it set same current value `setValue(value)`, you will see there is not recalculation happening.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I can't help thinking the term name is a bit misleading as it's not really memoizing the result - it's simply a change detection technique. That said, as long as I know, I can work with it.